# Port Silverlight Storyboard to WPF

Tags: wpf, silverlight, storyboard

Trying to port to WPF some behavior from an old Silverlight application that allowed users to configure their view by moving/minimizing/maximizing various UserControls.  Several StoryBoards were declared in UserControl.Resources and later accessed from code via their x:Name.

```
<Storyboard x:Name="MaximizeStoryboard" Completed="MaximizeStoryboard_Completed" Storyboard.TargetName="WholeControl">
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Width)">
                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame x:Name="MaximizeWidth" KeyTime="00:00:00.3000000" Value="0"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
...
```

In WPF, after changing x:Name to x:Key, I can access the Storyboard via:

```
Storyboard maximizeStoryboard = (Storyboard)Resources["MaximizeStoryboard"];
```

Previously used

```
MaximizeWidth.Value = Container.Contents.ActualWidth;
```

to set the restore width (and other values) from code, before beginning the animation.  That doesn't work in WPF.  What is the proper way to get access so those values can be set from code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the possible way can be go through the children of `Storyboard`, find `DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames` child and then get the first `KeyFrame`.

```
Storyboard maximizeStoryboard = (Storyboard)Resources["MaximizeStoryboard"];
var doubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames = maximizeStoryboard.Children.OfType<DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>().FirstOrDefault();
if (doubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames != null)
{
    if (doubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames.Count > 0)
    {
        var keyFrame = doubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames[0] as SplineDoubleKeyFrame;
        if(keyFrame !=null)
        {
            keyFrame.Value = Container.Contents.ActualWidth;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  That works.  If there's no rough equivalent to being able to access the property via x:Name, it seems like, in WPF, there's little value to declaring the animation in xaml.  Probably just as easy to do the entire animation in code?